# put each chunk of smaller array inside each row

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a large array which I converted into multidimensional array of 7 smaller chunks/groups. now I want each off these group to show in each row of table, having number of `td`'s equal to number of items in each chunk. for example my array is:

```
var arr = ["OH","2090923","14 Dec 2017","01 Jan 2018","01 Jan 2018","1.0","Approval","CL","105452","31 Jan 2018","07 Feb 2018","07 Feb 2018","0.5","Approval","CL","2100909","06 Feb 2018","06 Feb 2018","06 Feb 2018","0.5","Approval","CL","105452","06 Feb 2018","16 Mar 2018","16 Mar 2018","1.0","Approval","ML","2100909","09 Feb 2018","09 Feb 2018","09 Jul 2018","151.0","Approval","PL","2130989","09 Feb 2018","12 Feb 2018","16 Feb 2018","5.0","Approval"]
```

Now I divided it into chunks of 7 each, but want to display in table as:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>OH</td>
        <td>2090923</td>
        <td>14 Dec 2017</td>
        <td>01 Jan 2018</td>
        <td>01 Jan 2018</td>
        <td>1.0</td>
        <td>Approval</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>CL</td>
        <td>105452</td>
        <td>31 Jan 2018</td>
        <td>07 Feb 2018</td>
        <td>07 Feb 2018</td>
        <td>0.5</td>
        <td>Approval</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

but my code is displaying as:

```
<table class="tbl">

    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>OH,2090923,14 Dec 2017,01 Jan 2018,01 Jan 2018,1.0,Approval</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>CL,105452,31 Jan 2018,07 Feb 2018,07 Feb 2018,0.5,Approval</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>CL,2100909,06 Feb 2018,06 Feb 2018,06 Feb 2018,0.5,Approval</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>CL,105452,06 Feb 2018,16 Mar 2018,16 Mar 2018,1.0,Approval</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ML,2100909,09 Feb 2018,09 Feb 2018,09 Jul 2018,151.0,Approval</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>PL,2130989,09 Feb 2018,12 Feb 2018,16 Feb 2018,5.0,Approval</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

each chuck is coming inside a full `<td>` , please help.

fsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/23ojbmkp/3/

Comment: I kinda don't know what to tell ya.  I mean, you are taking the value and putting it inside a single td in your append.  You're not doing anything to take each of those values and put them each in a td.  You're one loop away from having what you want.

Comment: Why are you using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`? They just undo each other, and the result is just a copy of the original array.

Answer (score 2):

```js
 var createGroupedArray = function(arr, chunkSize) {
        var groups = [], i;
        
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i += chunkSize) {
            groups.push(arr.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
        }
        return groups;
    }
    var arr = ["OH","2090923","14 Dec 2017","01 Jan 2018","01 Jan 2018","1.0","Approval","CL","105452","31 Jan 2018","07 Feb 2018","07 Feb 2018","0.5","Approval","CL","2100909","06 Feb 2018","06 Feb 2018","06 Feb 2018","0.5","Approval","CL","105452","06 Feb 2018","16 Mar 2018","16 Mar 2018","1.0","Approval","ML","2100909","09 Feb 2018","09 Feb 2018","09 Jul 2018","151.0","Approval","PL","2130989","09 Feb 2018","12 Feb 2018","16 Feb 2018","5.0","Approval"]
    
    var groupedArr = createGroupedArray(arr, 7);
    
    for(i=0;i < groupedArr.length;i++){
    
      var temp = '';
      for(var j = 0; j < groupedArr[i].length; j++)
        temp += '<td>' + groupedArr[i][j] + '</td>';
      $(".tbl").append('<tr>' + temp + '</tr>');          
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tbl">
</table>
```

- You don't need `var result = JSON.stringify(groupedArr);` and `var res=JSON.parse(result);`.
- `i<=res.length` should be `i < res.length`.
- Use nested `for` loops.
- Can be done in one `for` loop if you refactor the `createGroupedArray` function.

Comment: `.append()` operates on the DOM, not HTML. You can't append `<td>` to the table, you have to append it to the row, and then append the row to the table.

Comment: Thanks Ali, you saved my day.

Comment: @user3450590 no worries. Please vote up/ accept as answer if that helped

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the elements in the nested array, and append them each as a `<td>` to the current `<tr>`.

```js
var createGroupedArray = function(arr, chunkSize) {
  var groups = [],
    i;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i += chunkSize) {
    groups.push(arr.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
  }
  return groups;
}
var arr = ["OH", "2090923", "14 Dec 2017", "01 Jan 2018", "01 Jan 2018", "1.0", "Approval", "CL", "105452", "31 Jan 2018", "07 Feb 2018", "07 Feb 2018", "0.5", "Approval", "CL", "2100909", "06 Feb 2018", "06 Feb 2018", "06 Feb 2018", "0.5", "Approval", "CL", "105452", "06 Feb 2018", "16 Mar 2018", "16 Mar 2018", "1.0", "Approval", "ML", "2100909", "09 Feb 2018", "09 Feb 2018", "09 Jul 2018", "151.0", "Approval", "PL", "2130989", "09 Feb 2018", "12 Feb 2018", "16 Feb 2018", "5.0", "Approval"]
var groupedArr = createGroupedArray(arr, 7);
var table = $(".tbl");
$.each(groupedArr, function() {
  var row = $("<tr>");
  $.each(this, function() {
    row.append($("<td>", {
      text: this
    }));
  });
  table.append(row);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tbl">
</table>
```